# jQuery .next() not working, element stays empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add html to a `div` using jQuery `.next()` but I get no results.

This is the html part :

```
<div class="widget widget_border">

  <h3 class="widget_border" id="widget_lot">Last opened tasks 
      <div class="dashboard_dd_arrow"></div>
  </h3>
  <div class="widget_content"></div>
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
(document).ready(function () {
  $('.widget h3').on('click', function () {
    if (!$.trim($(this).next('.widget_content').html())) {
      // if this widget don't have any data send ajax and load it

      var widget_id = $(this).attr('id');
      switch (widget_id) {
      case 'widget_lot':
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/dashboard/ajax_last_opened_tickets',
          data: {},
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(this).next('.widget_content').html('test');
          }
        });
        break;
      }
    } else {
      // show current one
      $(this).next('.widget_content').slideToggle().parent().toggleClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Ajax call goes well, I get the desired data but the `.next()` function doesn't fill the `div` with `widget_content` class.

Any solutions or ideas about this?

Thank you.

Comment: .children not .next , looks for an element following the current element

Comment: I think next is fine becuase op is looking div.widget_content from h3.. which is next element not children.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rohitbatham/UEg38/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need backup this in child function

```
$('.widget h3').on('click', function(){
    if( !$.trim($(this).next('.widget_content').html()) )
    {
        // if this widget don't have any data send ajax and load it

        var widget_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var _this = this; // backup this
        switch (widget_id) {
            case 'widget_lot':
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: '/dashboard/ajax_last_opened_tickets',
                    data:{},
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $(_this).next('.widget_content').html('test'); //edit here
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        // show current one
        $(this).next('.widget_content').slideToggle().parent().toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to cache `$(this)` reference outiside that ajax call and use it inside of its success call back. like,

```
 _this.next('.widget_content').html('test');
```

Note : `_this` in the above code has been added for a demonstration purpose only.

Comment: @zinho Glad to help..! If you think that this answer has helped you, then try to click on the tick mark which is present on the top left corner of this answer. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX function, `$(this)` is not what you think it is because it is referring to the success function/ajax request. You should do something like this:

```
var $self = $(this);
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url: '/dashboard/ajax_last_opened_tickets',
     data:{},
     success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
         $self.next('.widget_content').html('test');
     }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

$(this) inside success is pointing to current method not the top one. save to a variable.

```
( document ).ready(function() {
$('.widget h3').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if( !$.trim($this.next('.widget_content').html()) )
    {
        // if this widget don't have any data send ajax and load it

        var widget_id = $this.attr('id');
        switch (widget_id) {
            case 'widget_lot':
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url: '/dashboard/ajax_last_opened_tickets',
                    data:{},
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        $this.next('.widget_content').html('test');
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        // show current one
        $this.next('.widget_content').slideToggle().parent().toggleClass('active');
    }
});
});
```